# Understanding Autofac lifetime scopes

Tags: c#, autofac

From the documentation of Autofac, I understand that it keeps a reference to every IDisposable implementor that it creates. Therefore it can lead to OutOfMemoryException. So the suggested way to resolve dependencies is by using a ILifetimeScope.

Assume IService implements IDisposable.

```
class MaintenanceTask {
    private IService service;
    public MaintenanceTask(ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope) {
        service = lifetimeScope.Resolve<IService>();
    }
    //...do your work
}
```

But the problem with this approach is that it hides dependencies. I have to look at the code to see what that class depends on. Is there any other way to handle this in a more explicit way? More specifically, making dependencies more obvious without having to look at code? Or am I totally mistaken?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Passing in a lifetime scope is like passing in the container itself. It resembles the [Service locator (anti-) pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx) and has exactly the problem you described:
Dependecies become non-obvious.

One thing to ask yourself:
Are you actually having problems with your memory? If not, I wouldn't bother.

Another pointer:
If you have individual services that should be disposed right after usage, use a factory to create them and make your class depend on the factory instead of the service itself.

The usage scenario for lifetime scopes is a little bit different:
They are used when you need a local composition root. I never had the need for something like this in a windows application, but in web applications a Session or Request can require a local composition root.

Comment: I haven't had any memory problems yet. I am just trying guard against future problems. I am going to use autofac in an windows application + service so I shouldn't bother.

Comment: @idursun: You shouldn't bother in general. But you might still have some individual services that need disposing. For those, use a factory.

Comment: Note, an easy alternative to the factory is to resolve a Func<Owned<IService>>. This gives you a factory delegate that produces a disposable that contains the service. This prevents the disposable service to be tracked in the container.

Comment: @PeterLillevold: Where would you put that resolve? If you are not using the service locator anti-pattern you don't actually resolve `IService` yourself.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: sorry, when I think "resolve" I actually mean "take a dependency on". I'm all for not using a service locator. So in this case: `public MaintenanceTask(Func<Owned<IService>> serviceFactory)`.

Comment: @PeterLillevold: Ah, thanks for the clarification. If the factory would simply be a wrapper around `new` I like this approach better. I will use it in my code in the future, as it really cuts down on those simple factories.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: well, it's more than just a wrapper around new. The delegate cooked up by Autofac will, when called, do the same resolve operation as would have been performed if you used constructor injection directly (in this case, `public MaintenanceTask(Owned<IService> service)`). The added benefit obviously, is that the lifetime of the service is no longer bound to that of the consumer instance. You get to decide when the service needs to be constructed. Also, combined with `Owned<>` you explicitly state that you want the responsibility to decide when the service should be destroyed too.

Comment: @PeterLillevold: I understood that, sorry if my comment was unclear. What I meant with the "simple wrapper around new" was the following: This approach only works if the factory it replaces doesn't contain any logic beside newing up the instance and supplying dependencies.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: ah, yes, absolutely, I see your point now. Then again, if you have such logic, say, a `ServiceBuilder`, you can register that to create `IService` instances, yet still take the same `Func<Owned<IService>>` dependency. `MaintenanceTask` will continue to be oblivious to what is producing `IService` instances and how.

Comment: @PeterLillevold: Good idea, you could indeed do that.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was irksome enough to me that I created a library just to solve it.

Take a look at [Dependable](https://github.com/YairHalberstadt/Dependable).

With it your code changes to:

```cs
class MaintenanceTask {
    private IService service;
    public MaintenanceTask(IScopeFactory<IService> serviceFactory) {
        using(var serviceScope = serviceFactory.CreateScope())
        {
             service = serviceScope.Value;
             //...do your work
        }
    }
}
```