# Change AutoFac Default Behaviour

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

By default Autofac will hold onto any disposables it resolves till the end of a lifetime scope. If the LifeTimeScope is never or rarely ended, this will cause memory leaks.

This default doesn't work well for us - we would prefer that whenever we resolve a disposable which is instance per dependency, we are in control of disposing it, and Autofac does not hold on to the instance. If however the disposable is `InstancePerLifeTimeScope` or `SingleInstance`, we want Autofac to hold onto it and dispose it.

Currently this means we have to call `ExternallyOwned` on every registration.

Is there any way to change Autofacs default behavior, or to otherwise monkey patch either the builder or the container to make all registrations externally owned programmatically?

Comment: If the scope isn't ended, isn't that going to be a memory leak on its own? Seems like a very odd requirement.

Comment: @DavidG

As I said, it's rarely ended. But we are newing up a lot of services quite often, and that can lead to hundreds of MB of unused services before the lifetime scope ends.

Comment: could you provide code sample here that causes that question. Seems like bad design is there - if we talk about memory cache need to have expiration, etc. Please provide more details for your question

Comment: @Vladimir. Eg. We resolve a `Func<string, IService>()`. The` IService` is `IDisposable`, and registered as `InstancePerDependency` (This is necessary, as the string is different each time the func is called). A LifeTimeScope represents doing a single unit of work, and we will create and dispose of many thousands of these services over the course of a lifetime scope.

Comment: Create more scopes then...

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to change this default behavior nor to monkey patch the builder and it seems to be a bad design. Creating child scope or using `Owned` would be the way to go. Would that be possible ?

Comment: The reason why I'm not creating more scopes is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13859671/understanding-autofac-lifetime-scopes